# Optimizing for loop in Python to work faster

Tags: python, optimization, cprofile

I am working to optimize Python code. The goal is to take a list of integers and calculate and output how many pairs there are in the list. A pair is considered to be 2 numbers with the difference of **`K`** ( `2` in this case)
For example:

```
k = 2
list = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```

The pairs here will be `(1,3), (5,3), (2,4)`
The answer is: `3`

**I want to increase efficiency of the code**, current version takes 8 second or more.

**`cProfile`** tells me that `for number in sorted_array:` is the only line that takes all the time. But I cannot seem to figure out how to optimize `for` loop.

Does anyone have any experience or suggestions? Thank you so much.

The code:

```
#generate random numbers
import bisect
import random
n_integers = random.sample(xrange(1, 29999), 29998)
####cProfile
import cProfile
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

#the difference between numbers we are looking for
k = 2
sorted_array = []
pairs_counter = 0

#insert N integers in array in sorted fashion and typecast
for number in n_integers:
    bisect.insort_left(sorted_array, number)

#iterate over the array and calculate (number + K)
for number in sorted_array:
    the_pair = number + k
    #check if the number+K is in the array
    if the_pair in sorted_array:
        pairs_counter += 1

print pairs_counter

#Close cProfile
pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort = 'time')
```

cProfile:

```
30075 function calls in 7.995 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    7.834    7.834    7.834    7.834 <ipython-input-5-19d578e3c582>:19(<module>)
    29998    0.143    0.000    0.143    0.000 {_bisect.insort_left}
        1    0.016    0.016    0.159    0.159 <ipython-input-5-19d578e3c582>:15(<module>)
```

Comment: What is the expected output when you have an input with duplicates such as `[1,3,3,3,6]`?

Comment: I'm getting `30004 function calls in 0.091 seconds` Is it possible that your computer is just slow?

Comment: I too got a runtime with the exact code of .147 sec. (late 2012 macbook pro 15")

Comment: @MorganThrapp: [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html)

Comment: @MorganThrapp I have a last year generation mac with 8Gb DDR3 of RAM and 2.6 i5 processor. Probably your computer is too strong?)))) But that is the great result. I am running code in iPython notebooks, so I tried in console - the result is the same >7 seconds for 30000 calls.

Comment: @shuttle87 Numbers in the list must be unique. Mea culpa.

Comment: @solarguard89 I don't know what to tell you, but no one else seems to be able to reproduce your results.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I suspect bisect is coming from the random number generation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[1,3,3,3,3,3,6]` results in five *pairs* (`k=2`), you could use `numpy`'s [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) *feature* to eliminate the Python `for` loops.

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = random.sample(xrange(1, 29999), 29998)
a = np.array(a)
# or just a = np.random.randint(1, 29999, 29998)

k = 2
```

Create a new array that contains all the integers that would make *pairs*

```
b = a + k
```

Create a boolean array by broadcasting `b` across `a`: this results in a 2-d array with `True`'s everywhere there is a *pair*.

```
c = a[:, np.newaxis] == b
```

Sum all the `True`'s

```
np.sum(c)
```

Or just:

```
np.sum(a[:, np.newaxis] == b)
```

---

If, as the example *input* suggests, the list only contains unique values the `numpy` solution would be:

```
a = random.sample(xrange(1, 29999), 29998)
k = 2
a = np.array(a)
b = a + k
result = np.sum(np.in1d(b, a, assume_unique=True))
```

Which is much faster.

In fact if the values are NOT unique, `numpy.in1d` is much faster than the broadcasting solution, above.  By switching the order of the arguments, you *count* five pairs for `[1,3,3,3,3,3,6]`.

```
result = np.sum(np.in1d(a, b))
```

---

Now for a bit of crow eating:  turning the list to a set (assuming unique values), a *pure Python* solution is faster than the `numpy` solutions.

```
q = 10000
a = random.sample(xrange(1, q), q-1)
a = set(a)
result = sum(n+k in a for n in a)
```

Using `sum` to consume a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) doesn't require making any intermediate objects - probably one reason for its speed/efficiency.

Comment: I love the last solution that you proposed. It is extremely simple and elegant. How did you learn to do that? I am coming from Java background, probably that is why my code is so bulk. I want to learn to write it like you do.

Comment: @solarguard89 - Spend a lot of time reading the docs, start with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).  Work your way through some of the online learning materials.  Practice every example you come across - one of the cool things about an interpreted language is that it is very easy to try things out and play with ideas in the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a better algorithm.  In your code

```
for number in sorted_array:
    the_pair = number + k
    #check if the number+K is in the array
    if the_pair in sorted_array:
        pairs_counter += 1
```

you are checking the entire array for `the_pair`, so you have gained nothing by sorting the list.  Since all the elements are integers, after the list is sorted `the_pair, if it occurs in the list can only be in one of the next two positions.  Try something like

```
for index, number in sorted_array:
    if number+k in sorted_array[index+1:index+k+1]:
        <do whatever>
```

Comment: What if the sequence included something like - ```1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3```?

Comment: @wwii Good point.  I would say that there was only one pair, but I'm not sure what the OP wants.  On the other hand, if the list included 1,2,2,2,2,3 I wouldn't detect the (1,3).    So, if my interpretation of the question is correct, I should have made a set out of the list first.  If multiple instances of the same pair are required, then an inner while loop would work.

Comment: @wwii Actually, doesn't random.sample give a sample without replacement?  That's why I originally thought the numbers were distinct, but it slipped my mind when I saw your comment.

Comment: You are right, ```random.sample``` returns unique elements.  Maybe use a ```set``` instead of a sorted list., ```x in s``` would be O(1), for small ```k``` a slight improvement.

Comment: I think you're right, but the OP's question was "how to optimize the for loop," and that's what I was trying to address.

Comment: @saulspatz That is a very good point. Thank you very much. Unfortunately I cannot upvote posts yet. That actually gave me a result of 0.176 sec. By the way, do you need to put enumerate over sorted_array? for index, number in enumerate(sorted_array):    It doesn't work for me the other way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@saulspatz is correct that you are making sorting irrelevant in your code, however I would suggest you skip the sorting instead of generating thousands of list slices. The `in` operation is in fact extremely fast provided you are comparing to an immutable type (ex:`tuple()`). I therefore would propose the following code:

```
#generate random numbers
import bisect
import random
n_integers = tuple(random.sample(xrange(1, 29999), 29998))
####cProfile
import cProfile
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

#the difference between numbers we are looking for
k = 2
pairs_counter = 0

#iterate over the array and calculate (number + K)
for number in n_integers:
    the_pair = number + k
    #check if the number+K is in the array
    if the_pair in n_integers:
        pairs_counter += 1

print pairs_counter

#Close cProfile
pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort = 'time')
```

output:

```
29996
     1 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of'_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple *pairs* - e.g. ```(1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)```?

Comment: ```x in s``` takes the same time for a ```tuple``` and a ```list```, O(n).

Comment: @Aaron unfortunately for me this code produces the result in 11 seconds(((